# Columns are not holding margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Bootstrap 3.3.7. I cannot understand why my smaller columns are not holdning margin with the bigger columns. [See the demo here](http://vouzalis.dk/stack.html).

I have a `10px` margin between the columns.

Fx. there first row have the following columns: `600x410px` - `600x200px` `300x200px`.

So `200px + 200px + 10px margin = 410 height`. Therefore I gave the big column a height of `410px`.

Why are they not aligning then?

```css
/* Card and Button */

    body {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    div { 
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .index-content a:hover {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .index-content {
      /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
      /*padding: 50px 0px;*/
    }

    .index-content .row {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .index-content a {
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    .index-content .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card img {
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      height: 350px;
    }

    .index-content .card h4 {
      margin: 20px;
    }

    .index-content .card p {
      margin: 20px;
      opacity: 0.65;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button {
      width: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
      /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
      min-height: 20px;
      background-color: #002E5B;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button:hover {
      background-color: #dadada;
      color: #002E5B;
    }

    /* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */

    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .card {
            position: relative;
        }
        .card-content {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
        .card-content h4,
        .card-content p {
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 5px;
        }
        .card-content a {
            float: right;
        }
        .index-content .card h4,
        .index-content .card p {
            padding: 15px 20px;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .index-content .card p {
            padding: 0 20px 15px;
            margin: 0;
        }
    }

    .margin_bottom{
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .row [class*="col-"]{ 
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px; 
    }
    .row { 
        margin-left: -5px; 
        margin-right: -5px; 
    }
    
    .card-img-bottom {
  color: #fff;
  height: 20rem;
  background: url(images/img1.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.img-responsive {width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <!--<h3>Grid 1</h3>-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x410" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!--<h3>Grid 2</h3>-->
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!--<h3>Grid 3</h3>-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x410" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x410" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<h3>Grid 4</h3>-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x410" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `float` isn't the right tool for layout like that. Your images are responsive, so they will not necessary have the size you gave them, but your paddings and margin are not responsive and won't change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.img-responsive { height: 100%; }` instead of `.img-responsive {width:100%; }`. please check the below working example. hope it helps :)

and as per suggestion setting width in smaller screens: `@media (max-width: 768px) { .img-responsive { width: 100%; } }`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
/* Card and Button */
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
div {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.index-content a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.index-content .row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.index-content a {
  color: black;
}
.index-content .card {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.index-content .card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: black;
}
.index-content .card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  height: 350px;
}
.index-content .card h4 {
  margin: 20px;
}
.index-content .card p {
  margin: 20px;
  opacity: 0.65;
}
.index-content .blue-button {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: #002E5B;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.index-content .blue-button:hover {
  background-color: #dadada;
  color: #002E5B;
}


/* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    position: relative;
  }
  .card-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .card-content h4,
  .card-content p {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
  }
  .card-content a {
    float: right;
  }
  .index-content .card h4,
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 0 20px 15px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
.margin_bottom {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.row [class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.row {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
.card-img-bottom {
  color: #fff;
  height: 20rem;
  background: url(images/img1.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.img-responsive {
  height: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>


<div class="container">
  <!--<h3>Grid 1</h3>-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/600x410" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<h3>Grid 2</h3>-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 margin_bottom">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 margin_bottom">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<h3>Grid 3</h3>-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x410" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x410" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<h3>Grid 4</h3>-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x410" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. When I remove the width:100% and set height to 100% - the responsive grid will not work. The columns are not taking full width `< 768px`

Comment: in that case remove class `.img-responsive {height: 100%;}`, there is no need to set `height` or `width`, tested it just now, it will work fine, with few minor spacing issue between image, hope that is not too major.

Comment: Hello again. You can see the demoversion of your suggestion here: http://vouzalis.dk/test.html. Below 768 the columns are not taking full width if I completly remove the class `.img-responsive`.

Comment: in that case why do u want to scale a image of dimension `300x410` to 100% width, it will look ugly and scaled, once u add the actual images in place of those placeholders

Comment: What about this solution? `.img-responsive { height: 100%; }

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    }
}`

Comment: nice, can do, it depends upon your requirement though